# Group by query based on other column value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

Suppose I have a table named `process_states`:

```
+--------+--------+
|Process | State  |
-------------------
|   A    |   0    |
|   A    |   0    |
|   B    |   0    |
|   B    |  -1    |
|   C    |  -99   |
-------------------
Note: State can have many more negative and positive state values
```

> I want to find all processes having all rows with state 0. In the above case I want to get A.

I am trying to do it using `group by`, is there a way to do something like this:

```
select process from process_states 
group by process 
having <all state for that process is 0>
```

Is it possible to do it using `group by`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `group by` clause and filter the processes with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   process
FROM     process_states
GROUP BY process
HAVING   COUNT(CASE state WHEN -1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

EDIT:

Given the clarifying comments on other answers, if the requirement is to find only processes that only have `0` states, you could count the total number of rows and the number of rows with a `0` state and compare them:

```
SELECT   process
FROM     process_states
GROUP BY process
HAVING   COUNT(CASE state WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Following up on the questions, if I want to find all processes having 0 or 1 can I use an `OR` in the count?

Comment: For any condition that isn't just a shorthand for an equality check, you'll have to use the longer form of `case`: `COUNT(CASE WHEN state IN (0, 1) THEN 1 END)`. Of course, you could just have a couple of `when` clauses: `COUNT(CASE state WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)`, but, well, yuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by` process column and check if the max and min of the state column is `0`.

```
select process 
from process_states
group by process
having max(state) = min(state) and min(state) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the `having` clause.  If the count of the rows for a given process is equal to the count of rows with zeroes, then it means that the process only has rows with zeroes.

```
select process
  from process_states
 group by process
 having count(*) = count(case when state = 0 then 'X' end)
```

Comment: Following up on the questions, if I want to find all processes having 0 or 1 can I use an `OR` in the count?

Comment: Change `when state = 0` to `when state IN (0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use `min` for this:

```
select process
from process_status
group by process
having min(status) > -1;
```

This does assume that there are no other negative status.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select process
from process_status
group by process
having sum(abs(status))  = 0
```